# RWY designation

Tags: landing, runways

I'm a translator, and currently I have some issues associated with RWY designation.
There is a runway with the magnetic direction 246°. How would you call it? 
So let me put it like this. In Wikipedia, they say that you truncate the three-digits magnetic direction to the first two figures and you get 24, while in some other places it is said to round the result up or down, so I shall get 25.
Which is correct? Will it be RWY24 or RW25?

Comment: Everything i've seen indicates rounding rather than truncating, though I /haven't/ seen any mentions if headings ending in 5 use round-to-even or something else.  …  Also, is this a real airport? You should just be able to find the published approach docs or similar if so. Heck a satellite map might verify the numbers physically​ (if the magnetic state of the area hasn't changed lately…)

Comment: @Pete what do you mean? There are many airports with parallel runways. Atlanta Hartsfield has even 5 runways in exactly the same direction. Approaching from the west they are named 8L, 8R, 9L 9R and 10 from north to south. So sometimes truncating, rounding & being creative is being used.